# what replaces indexPathForSelectedRow in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitableview

In projects prior to Swift 3 - If I was looking to segue an indexPath from a tableController, I'd have a line of code like

```
      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

However, in Swift 3, I am unable to write this. I can't seem to find any documentation on Apple's site or other SO questions to find a workable piece of code.

In response to Frankie's comment, I went back to my code (here is all of the current segue Swift 3 code) and have tried to copy and paste above code snippet... but to no avail. Xcode does not auto complete if I enter "self.tableView". It does not recognize indexPathForSelectedRow! either.  I'm missing something.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "dineSegue"
    {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? RestaurantController
        {
            let indexPath = DineController.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destinationViewController.restaurantIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled 'indexPathForSelectedRow Apple documentation` and was able to find the property reference for you as it was conveniently the first result.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow

That being said, it's exactly what you posted in Swift 3.

`self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`

Comment: updaated the question to show more. Copying and Pasting did not work. IndexPathForSelectedRow does not appear as an autofill option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "DineController" reference is to the actual UITableView

When I had this issue, my initial reference was to the generic class, not the actual table I had coded.